# QGIS not coming to foreground

Tags: qgis-3, windows

I recently upgraded from QGIS 3.2 to 3.4 using the standalone installer (Windows 64 bit), and uninstalling 3.2 beforehand.  When I open 3.4 it goes the background behind all my other open programs and clicking its icon on the taskbar does nothing, nor does Alt-Tab.  To use QGIS I have to minimize all my other open programs.

Is this a Windows issue, a QGIS issue, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but my problem began after running OSGeo4W setup. Since that time I've tried forcing a Reinstall but this didn't fix it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152796)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but it does provide  a little more detail since he used a different installer.  Another detail, it is related to my profile.  I launched QGIS with on a different account on this machine and it works just fine, the window focuses and comes to the foreground.  I'd prefer to find a solution, but I may have to just wipe this account and start another one.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information that you think relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I had to proceed to some deleting tests in the profile's QGIS3.ini file*, I figured out that the FastVersion plugin was at the origin of the issue. I uninstalled it and it works like a charm.

- We talk here about QGIS Profiles (Settings > User profiles) and the file is "C:\Users\PaCha\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini"