# QGIS 3.10.1 and 3.6 don't pull to front when clicked on taskbar?

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

There's a similar question already ([QGIS 3.4 won't come to the foreground](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302543/qgis-3-4-wont-come-to-the-foreground)), **but it's been left unanswered** and I don't have enough reputation to add a bounty, so please don't yell at me.

Like others in the linked thread, I think it's possible that it started after running OSGeo4W. I tried installing different versions (same result), through OSGeo4W and by using standalone installers. I got rid of OSGeo4W off my disc (just the main file), but it didn't do anything. There's also this cmake file that's included in every version and OSGeo4W? The only version that works fine on my laptop (3.2, installed long before that) does not have that file, so I removed it from 3.10.1 but it didn't help.

It's extremely annoying to have to minimise windows all the time.

Comment: Here are a couple of other places you could look for answers: https://superuser.com/, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers)